# in vs code im getting this error in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\vaibh\Desktop\java script\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter> live-server
live-server : File
C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- live-server
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PS  
  SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

PS C:\Users\vaibh\Desktop\java script\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter>

Comment: The error message seems pretty informative, it even links you to Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Try to run the below command and then try again:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```